# How to stop multiple loading of content page in UWP

Tags: uwp

I have an issue where we're calling ContentFrame.Navigate in a UWP Mainpage to load the Content page from the footer. The problem is you can press this button 20 times...and then have to press the BACK button 20 times to get back to the main frame.

```
 ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(LanguagePage));
```

Any ideas how to stop this sort of behaviour as I am not turning up much online. Failing that, hiding the button when the main page changes would also be an option?

BTW, we have inherited this application!

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP - exclude navigation from back button stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326032/uwp-exclude-navigation-from-back-button-stack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding button isn't the best solution. You can check current page type in Frame control:

```
if (Frame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(SomePage))
{
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When I updated that to:

`if (ContentFrame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(LanguagePage))
            {
                return;
            }`

it works exactly as I was after. Really appreciate the help.